# 404 Error in Tank Auth CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, tankauth

I'm relatively new to CodeIgniter and after going through couple of basic tutorials, here is what i did:

1.Modified .htaccess to removed index.php page as below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /digischool/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

2. Modified config.php as below:

   $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/testci/';

   $config['index_page'] = '';
3. Modifed Routes.php as :

   $route['default_controller'] = 'dashboard';

Now for authentication system I thought of using Tank Auth,and all I have did is downloaded the library, imported database and copied all files to respective folder.

Now when I am trying to access http://localhost/testci/auth/login,
 or /testci/dashboard/auth/login I'm getting 404 not found error.

I tried to search solution for this,but documentation and communicty support seems to be poor for Tank Auth integration. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**  My Fodler Structure [My Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5mWI.png)

Comment: did you follow this for file and class naming http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Your base url should be like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/testci/';` not `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/testci/';`

Comment: Yes,I have my base url as<code> http://localhost/testci/ </code> https is lost because of SF code formating. All other controllers which I have created are working fine and Tank Auth controller is only giving me 404 error. Regarding naming convention, I have created my controllers,model in uppercase but auth.php of Tank Auth is in lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last solution and fixed issue. Posting solution here for future use:

As per CI user guide naming convention,

> Class files must be named in a Ucfirst-like manner, while any other
>   file name (configurations, views, generic scripts, etc.) should be in
>   all lowercase.

But Tank Auth uses controller and model class names in lower case. So had to rename Tank Auth controller and model files to upper case and change the references according which worked for me.

Thanks @wolfgang1983 for your link to user guide naming convention which helped me in fixing the issue.